# Globally include User Eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel 5 site. I would like to use *User::find* function to every page of my Laravel site, views and controllers, such as Auth model. In Laravel 5 I have to include ("use") this model to every page, but I would like to have it for all of them. 
How can i do? 
User model is an example but it would be cool to have global variables for several Eloquent models. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your Eloquent models to the `aliases` list in `config/app.php`. For example, `'User' => 'App\User'` will make your User model available as `\User` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't understand the real problem there.

Based on my own L4 know-how, those models have global scope for default.

**Then, is that it's about PHP namespace. It's not about scope at all.**

Look at:

`namespace AnotherModel;`

`use User;`

It's all right. But, if you don't want it, so you need to do like below:

`class Foobar {`

`public function test () {`

`$users = \User::all ();`

`} }`

Then, you can use `\` to call the Model object without declaring its proper namespace. It's like some global scope.

Remember every Model object has its own namespace for autoloading reasons. Search for PSR patterns:

- [PSR-0](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/46/using-a-psr-0-directory-structure)
- [PSR-4](https://laracasts.com/lessons/psr-4-autoloading)

Plus one for understanding:

[Namespaces](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.namespaces.php)

Cheers; good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll have a look

Comment: You are welcome. Be aware before of treating Model as **IoC containers** or **Facades**.